# Dead outlet that make a volt sensor sing

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet that makes a volt sensor ring but nothing works when plugged in. My outlet tester doesn't do anything either...does that mean I have an open hot somewhere?

Comment: It means you have an open neutral somewhere.

Comment: If you plug in a circuit tester, it should tell you what the problem is. It could be an open neutral. Does your non contact voltage tester sound when it is inserted in the hot side (shorter slot) only and not sound when inserted into the neutral side (longer slot)? If it sounds in both slots, that could indicate that neither side is truly hot and these are just phantom voltages. It could mean that *both* are hot. It could mean that the hot has a poor connection (high resistance) so that insufficient current flows to operate an appliance or lamp. If so, the poor connection is a fire risk.

Comment: Do you have a volt meter?

Comment: It may also be half of a multi-wire branch circuit, and you only turned off that half.  This is two circuits on opposite poles sharing a neutral.